# Connecting a smartphone android camera while charging the phone

Tags: usb, charging, data

I am hoping for advice. I have a android camera (the same as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvWIp5vtsEU) and want to connect it to a Sony phone to see if I can use it as a streaming device. However, obviously the phone battery will eventually run out of current so I have to keep it on a charger permanently. The problem is that there is only one micro usb port on the phone. I have connected the positive and negative wires of an usb charger directly to the positive and negative of the probe camera’s cable. It works, but the phone either only picks up the camera and is not charging or is charging but is not picking up the camera. It depends on what is plugged in first. Do you have any advice so it will carry data while being charged at the same time?

Amazon sells the following:

[https://www.amazon.com/Kework-Micro-Splitter-Female-Extension/dp/B07ZZ8PNQF/ref=as_li_ss_tl?dchild=1&keywords=Micro+Usb+Splitter&qid=1601039265&sr=8-16&th=1&linkCode=sl1&tag=galtecrev-20&linkId=2b50e736895351b0d5f08d0dd550f486&language=en_US](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZZ8PNQF)

but it is out of stock and I have tried other local stores but no success.

Regards

Comment: Most phones simply cannot do that though a few allegedly can.  Anyway product usage questions are off topic.

Comment: Do some web searching and try to find a user forum where people discuss your particular phone model.